# Rotation tool not tilting

Tags: error

I have been trying to tilt a selected part of an arm to bend limbs, I try to tilt it to the right. However, it goes side to side.

Here is an example.

https://gyazo.com/e7639bcb68cb1c6a57ed61ffab05f9c8

Answer (score 0):

Select the armature and go to the "object" tab on the right side of the screen (orange box) and tick the option that says "In Front" (it's under "Visibility" or "Viewport Display" or something). This will always draw the bones in front of the mesh.

Change your rotation space to "Local" and pivot to "Active Element" at the top of the screen. With the armature selected, press CTRL-TAB to enterms pose mode. At the top of the screen, click the gizmos icon to bring up the drop down menu. Make sure the Rotation gizmo is activated.

Now you can see which axis your rotation is affecting by clicking and dragging the colored circles.